# How can I write pseudocode for the following diagram?

Tags: pseudocode

I failed to use the do-while or while loop for the following diagram:

[image]

Here, A, B, and C are functions. 
How can I write pseudocode for the diagram above?

EDIT: This is from my programming practice of C++. Without the "B loop" (or the "A loop"), I am able to write it as the following:

```
Start
Input x;
while(x!=2)
{
A(); Input x;
}
C();
End
```

However, when the "B loop" comes in, I have no idea how to include it.

Comment: Smells like homework. If you know say C#, just remove type info and lose the semi-colons.

Comment: Did you try anything? Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode

Comment: I should have written `A`, `B`, `C` as `A()`, `B()`, `C()`, since they are all functions.

Comment: @home: Yes I did. What confuses me is the two loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Start;

Input x;

while(x!=2){ 

    if (x!=1){
        A();
    } else{ 
        B()
    }
    Input x;
}

C();

End
```

But beware of the langage you are using I advise you to add a sleep mode between data aquisitions (Just before Input x)

Answer (score 2):

What does the program do? Explain it in English, then write it down. You then have your pseudocode.

```
If any input
 if input is not 1 and not 2
 return a  and do more input (? dont get the diagram here ;p)
 if input is 1
 return b and more input (??)
 else if not above
 return c and end program
```

Answer (score 2):

@BaptisteGousset 's answer is good, but there is an alternative way that could be better under certain circumstances. It is possible to use a do...while loop instead of a while to simplify the code to remove the doubled Input operation, but this makes the comparative logic a little more complex.

```
Start;
Do
{
    Input x;
    if (x equals 1)
    {
        B();
    }
    elseif(x not equal to 2)
    {
        A();
    }

} While (x not equal to 2);
C();
End;
```

You can also implement this using a goto statement, but goto is often [considered harmful](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf).

Generally, there is not a single canonical "pseudocode" answer for any flowchart - it depends on what structures you are willing to use and how elegantly those structures fit with your actual task.